# how to use php variables make query for sqlite3

Tags: php, sqlite

```
<?php
/**
 * Simple example of extending the SQLite3 class and changing the __construct
 * parameters, then using the open method to initialize the DB.
 */
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('wifin.db');
    }
}
$db = new MyDB();

$mac = 'test';
$ssid = $_POST['ssid'];
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lon = $_POST['lon'];

$db->exec("INSERT INTO wifinTb (mac,ssid,lat,lon) VALUES ($mac,$ssid,$lat,$lon)");

$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM wifinTb WHERE mac=$mac');

var_dump($result->fetchArray());

?>
```

i'm not sure how to use variables in php5, $mac should be a string, when i directly use `mac=$mac`, it return me bool(false), which means can't find, but when i use `mac='test'`, it gives me result.

Comment: RTFM: [PHP: Strings](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you initialize `$mac` with `'test'`, is what you are doing is assigning a string (PHP recognizes anything inside `''` or `""` as a string) to `$mac`. The value of this string is `test`. So you still need to surround the value in the query with `''`:

```
$db->exec("INSERT INTO wifinTb (mac,ssid,lat,lon) VALUES ('$mac','$ssid','$lat','$lon')");
```

Comment: i try to use `$db->exec('insert into wifinTb(mac,ssid,lat,lon)values("WTF","test500",1.0,2.0)')` but not working,but it works once before...

Comment: try the exact statement I put in my post. Use `'` insted of `"` in your SQL statement.

Comment: yes you are right, if '' outside, need using "" inside

Answer (score 5):

Never ever use string concatenation or replacement to put values into SQL statements; this will give you formatting problems (as you've seen) and allow [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Instead, use parameters:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO wifinTb(mac,ssid,lat,lon) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
$stmt->bindValue(1, 'test');
$stmt->bindValue(2, $_POST['ssid']);
$stmt->bindValue(3, $_POST['lat']);
$stmt->bindValue(4, $_POST['lon']);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM wifinTb WHERE mac = :mac');
$stmt->bindValue(':mac', $mac);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: XKCD was perfect right there!

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM wifinTb WHERE mac=$mac');
```

Is currently being seen as one long string. You could get around this quickly by changing it to:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM wifinTb WHERE mac='" . $mac . "'");
```

However, you'd be better reading up on PDO or mysqli bind functions rather than injecting like that.

Hope that helps?